# Scala Try/Future, wrapping the exception in case of failure

Tags: scala, try-catch, functor

Suppose I have a method `def doSomething: String` which can raise a `DoSomethingException` if something goes wrong.

If I write `Try(doSomething)`, is there a simple way to map the exception without recovering it?

Basically, I want the failure to become a `BusinessException` caused by the `DoSomethingException`.

I know the code to do this is very simple, but isn't there any built-in operator to do so? It seems a very common operation but I can't find anything in the API.

Comment: why you just don not want to throw this exception from your `doSomething`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `transform`

```
val t = Failure(new DoSomethingException)
val bt = t.transform(s => Success(s), e => Failure(new BusinessException))
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine. I would have expected something to only deal with the failure and not both, like mapFailure or something

Answer (score 24):

With recover:

```
val c = scala.util.Try(doSomething).recover { 
    case e: DoSomethingException => throw new BusinessException
}
```

Comment: this seems a pretty nice idea but produces compilation problems because the partial fonction return type is not inferred

Comment: it works for me, if the compiler can do the inference or not it seems depends on the context. In any case, you can make it explicit, but there is no logical or type problem with this solution.

Comment: @SebastienLorber `collect` may produce problems, but here left type is Throwable anyway

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `recoverWith`:

```
Try {
    doSomething
} recoverWith { 
    case e: DoSomethingException => Failure(new BusinessException)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can as well match on Try using PartialFunction (and unwrap the value if there were no failures):

```
Try(doSomething) match {
    case Success(result) => result
    case Failure(throwable) => new BusinessException(throwable)
  }
```

Comment: `match`, not `map`. Can't edit post because the edit length is too small.

Comment: @Shannon why don't you like map?

Comment: It doesn't compile. You can get it to compile if `doSomething` is an `Any`, but then what you get is a `Failure(scala.MatchError)`. `match` both compiles and does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

## ¡Warning!

> I'm interpreting the OP differently than the other answers!

### Solution

Since you said you want a "`BusinessException` caused by the `DoSomethingException`", why not do this?

`BusinessException.initCause(DoSomethingException)`

### Result

That would ultimately output *both as full exceptions* (stack traces and all) and a nice message in between explaining that the first was caused by the second.

### Commentary

It would still require a mapping of success and failure of some kind (e.g. the `transform` method you accepted) to avoid using restore.

Regardless, I wanted to put this here just in case you (or someone else) was looking for a genuine "caused by" semantic. That's what I was looking for when I found your question.